# Help for the integral of trigonometric function Gaussian kernel

Tags: definite-integrals

Can anyone give me some clues about the following integral
\begin{equation*}
\int_{R^{n}} \cos(\|x\|)\exp(-0.5(x - Ex)'C^{-1}(x - Ex))dx
\end{equation*}
where $\|x\|$ is the Euclidean norm.

I only know the following special case
\begin{equation*}
  \int_{R^{6}} \cos(x^{T}x) \mathcal{N}(x;0,I)dx = -3\text{Dawson}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)/2\sqrt{2}
\end{equation*}